# How to perform conversion from object reference

Tags: c#

```
class Mock
{
    public static explicit operator String(Mock s)
    {
        return "ok";
    }
}

static T GetValue<T>(object o)
{
    return (T)o;
}

Mock m = new Mock();
var v1 = (string) m;
var v2 = GetValue<string>(m);   // InvalidCastException is thrown.
                                // How to modify GetValue method
                                // internally, without changing its
                                // signature, for this casting to work ?
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

- Use reflection to find the conversion and invoke it
- Use dynamic typing if you're using C# 4

Using reflection is likely to be painful. The dynamic approach is simpler if you can get away with it:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(dynamic d)
{
    return (T) d;
}
```

That isn't a particularly drastic change to the signature, but if you wanted to keep it *exactly* the same, you could use:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(object o)
{
    dynamic d = o;
    return (T) d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the direct cast succeeds and the `GetValue` method fails is because the direct cast method is using the explicitcast operator on the `Mock<T>` type.  This explicit cast operator is not available in the generic version because the C# compiler only sees `T` and hence doesn't bind to the implicit conversion operator but instead chooses to do a CLR conversion.

The easiest way to get this to work is to add an interface to represent this conversion and then constraint `T` to implement the interface

```
interface IConvertToString {
  string Convert();
}

public class Mock : IConvertToString {
  public string Convert() {
    return "ok";
  }
}

public static T GetValue<T>(T o) where T : IConvertToString {
  return o.ConvertToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this: `var v2 = GetValue<string>((string)m);` ?

This does not modify the GetValue method, rather casts the parameter sent into it. You retain your signature. The cast looks a bit redundant but you have to specify the type for GetValue anyway...